# Trying to send 2 bytes string to Server

Tags: c#, string, server, client, byte

I have a given server that works by a specific protocol.
By that protocol, I need to send the server 3 different 2 bytes sized strings-email, password, username.

I don't exactly know how to do this...
I tried converting the string and change their size but it didn't work.

This is what I tried to do-

```
byte[] logInStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("203##" + usernameTB.Text + "##" + passwordTB.Text + "##" + emailTB.Text);

NetworkStream serverStream = serverStream.Write(logInStream, 0, logInStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `2 bytes sized strings`?

Comment: Yeah...what do you mean by "2 bytes"?   Are you referring to an acceptable encoding on the server.    You might try "System.Text.Encoding.UTF16...." instead.

Answer (score 0):

This premise is impossible. You cannot have a string with an email address that is of size 2 bytes. Each char is 1 byte, so unless your email address is 2 letters long, you can't make the string 2 bytes